# How to use nslookup to output IPv4 addresses for a domain name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, nslookup

Hope someone can help. I have been struggling with printing out the IPv4 addresses of a domain specified by a user. I have managed to get it to print out one IPv4 address for a domain name however for example: microsoft.com has multiple IPv4's addresses however I can only get it to print out `1`.

Thank you!

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set directory=%~1

if "%directory%"=="" (
    :menu
    echo Welcome to Domain Name Lookup
    echo Please select the option you want to proceed:
    echo 1. Input a domain name
    echo 2. Quit from the program

    choice /c 12 /n /m "Please select an option: "

    if "!errorlevel!"=="1" (

        set /p domain=Please enter the domain name: 

        echo Performing DNS lookup for !domain!
        echo -------------------

        for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup -type=A !domain! 2^>nul ^| findstr /C:"Address"') do (
            echo Domain: !domain!
            echo Address: %%a
        )
```

I've tried to change `Address` to `Addressess` as it appears in `nslookup` but was unsuccessful. I've attached an image of what my program displays, and also what it is supposed to display:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIWNy.png]